# display: inline for HTML5 elements

Tags: html, css

I am looking to make a horizontally layed website but I am having issues with the display: inline rule.

It seems to be tailored towards inline navigational unordered lists, completely overwriting the height and width set for the articles (and or the sections) in the CSS.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="container">
   <section id="about" class="first">
    <article>
     About Us
    </article>
   </section><!--about-->

   <section id="projects">
    <article>
     Project 1
    </article>
    <article>
     Project 2
    </article>
    <article>
     Project 3
    </article>
    <article>
     Project 4
    </article>
    <article>
     Project 5
    </article>
   </section><!--projects-->

   <section id="blog">
    <article>
     Blog 1
    </article>
    <article>
     Blog 2
    </article>
    <article>
     Blog 3
    </article>
    <article>
     Blog 4
    </article>
    <article>
     Blog 5
    </article>
   </section><!--blog-->

   <section id="contact">
    <article>
     Contact
    </article>
   </section><!--contact-->

   <section id="tweets">
    <article>
     Tweets
    </article>
   </section><!--tweets-->

   <section id="comments">
    <article>
     Comments
    </article>
   </section><!--comments-->

   <section id="links">
    <article>
     Links
    </article>
   </section><!--links-->

        </div> <!--container-->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#container{
 height: 600px;
 display: inline;
}

section{
 display: inline;
}

article{
 height: 600px;
 width: 300px;
 display: inline;
}
```

This is what it looks like:

http://danixd.com/archive/html5.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Hasn't that always been the case? `display:inline` is for inline elements, which don't have heights and widths. Maybe you're looking for `inline-block`?

Comment: In HTML4 / CSS2 I have a set of divs that span horizontally.

I have already set the display of the HTML 5 elements to display: block in the start of the CSS. I have only started looking at HTML5, but in most cases it says you are required to do this. 

I see no reason why it would ignore the height /width set in the CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#container{
 height: 600px;
 float: left;
 overflow: auto;
}

section{
 float: left;
}

article{
 height: 600px;
 width: 300px;
 float: left;
}
```

Read: http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline.php

Elements with a css propety of `display: inline` aren't intended for your purposes.

Comment: The combination of 
article{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

section{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

and... setting the body width, thanks guys!

Comment: The combination is irrelevant, once you start floating, the display property is largely ignored. Try removing the `display: inline-block`.